# Is there a way to consistently change my background css depending on the input?

Tags: javascript, css

So ive been trying to change my background css depending on the weather whether it says "Clouds" "Sunny" etc but for some reason it wont change?
As i call the API it just returns a dark screen for the "Clouds" attribute but when i type in a new location the background is still "Clouds" when it should be "Sunny"
This is my code so far

```js
const mainWeatherAttribute = [];
if (oneCallDataFromApi !== undefined && oneCallDataFromApi != null) {
  oneCallDataFromApi.current.weather.map((item) =>
    mainWeatherAttribute.push(item.main)
  );
}
console.log(`Main Weather Attributes: ${mainWeatherAttribute}`);

if (mainWeatherAttribute.includes("Clear")) {
  document.body.classList.add("background-warm");
  mainWeatherAttribute.splice(0, mainWeatherAttribute.length);
} else if (mainWeatherAttribute.includes("Clouds")) {
  document.body.classList.add("background-cloudy");
  mainWeatherAttribute.splice(0, mainWeatherAttribute.length);
  console.log(mainWeatherAttribute);
}
```

```css
.background-warm {
  background: linear-gradient( 179.31deg, rgba(204, 101, 26, 0.97) 9.28%, #fdfeff 167.45%);
}

.background-clear {
  background: linear-gradient( 179.31deg, rgba(120, 192, 197, 0.97) 9.28%, #FDFEFF 167.45%);
}

.background-thunderstorm {
  background: linear-gradient( 179.31deg, rgba(87, 42, 182, 0.97) 9.28%, #fdfeff 167.45%);
}

.background-cloudy {
  background: linear-gradient( #000000, #fdfeff 167.45%);
}
```

Comment: can you share the rest of the code and make a snippet out of it. Have you defined the styles for the classes you are adding?

Comment: @Aalexander Yes i believe so

```
.background-warm {
  background: linear-gradient(
    179.31deg,
    rgba(204, 101, 26, 0.97) 9.28%,
    #fdfeff 167.45%
  );
}
``` 
 This is one example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding classes but not removing them.. it will use the default first value logic.. you want to just overwrite the className instead :D

**ALSO**: I'm not seeing the rest of your code but it seems like you should have an interval(`setInterval` logic) for this part below for it to get api data and change frequently although I guess your `console.log` would occur many times as new api calls are made(so i assume you frequently call the api and run that block you showed me in your question)

```
const mainWeatherAttribute = [];
if (oneCallDataFromApi !== undefined && oneCallDataFromApi != null) {
  oneCallDataFromApi.current.weather.map((item) =>
    mainWeatherAttribute.push(item.main)
  );
}
console.log(`Main Weather Attributes: ${mainWeatherAttribute}`);

if (mainWeatherAttribute.includes("Clear")) {
  document.body.className="background-warm";
  mainWeatherAttribute.splice(0, mainWeatherAttribute.length);
} else if (mainWeatherAttribute.includes("Clouds")) {
  document.body.className="background-cloudy";
  mainWeatherAttribute.splice(0, mainWeatherAttribute.length);
  console.log(mainWeatherAttribute);
}
```

An example of using `setInterval` in case you don't call the api frequently(according to the code you showed it looks like you only call it once)

```
const mainWeatherAttribute = [];

let i=setInterval(async()=>{
  const oneCallDataFromApi=await howeverYouGetYourData()
  if (oneCallDataFromApi !== undefined && oneCallDataFromApi != null) {
    oneCallDataFromApi.current.weather.map((item) =>
    mainWeatherAttribute.push(item.main)
    );
  }
  console.log(`Main Weather Attributes: ${mainWeatherAttribute}`);

  if (mainWeatherAttribute.includes("Clear")) {
    document.body.className="background-warm";
    mainWeatherAttribute.splice(0, mainWeatherAttribute.length);
  } else if (mainWeatherAttribute.includes("Clouds")) {
    document.body.className="background-cloudy";
    mainWeatherAttribute.splice(0, mainWeatherAttribute.length);
    console.log(mainWeatherAttribute);
  }
},3000)//the number is milliseconds.. you can change this to change how frequently the block is run
```

Comment: Thank you this solved my issue greatly, didnt know className was autodefined in CSS without actually having to write "className ="